# Validity of constant functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, definition

Is a constant function, like $y = 3$, defined for all inputs?

A function is defined at some arbitrary point if it has a value at that point, yes?

And constant functions have values for all inputs, namely the constant.

So they should be defined for all inputs, right?

I'm learning about Maclaurin's series, and it states that the function and its nth derivatives must be defined at $x = 0$.

Would it work with a constant function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, *yes*. But it can depend on how you define the function. Generally when we write $y = 3$ we mean the function $y : \mathbb{R} \to \{3\}$. In this case, it is defined for all real input.

However, if we defined something like $y : [0,1] \to \{3\}$, then it is not well-defined for all real input.

Comment: It is technically incorrect to say that the function $y:[0,1] -> \{3\}$ is not well-defined for all reals; I think you mean to say "$y$ is not defined for all real input".  A function $f:X \to Y$ is *well-defined* if for every value $x$ in the domain there is precisely one value $y$ in the codomain such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: @AaronDall is there a difference between "not well-defined for all real input" and "not defined for all real input"? I'm not aware of a rigorous definition for the modifier _well_ and I would interpret them the same way in this instance.

Comment: Yes, there is a difference. A function is a triple $(X,Y,G)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are sets and $G$ is a set of ordered pairs such that for all $x \in X$ there is *precisely* one $y \in Y$ such that $(x,y) \in G$. A *relation* is a triple $(X,Y,G)$ such that for each $x \in X$ there is *at least* one $y \in Y$ such that $(x,y) \in G$. A relation $R = (X,Y,G)$ is said to be *defined* at $z$ if and only if $z \in X$. The  relation $R$ is *well-defined* at $z \in X$ if and only if there is precisely one $y \in Y$ such that $(x,y) \in G$.

Comment: So a relation $(X,Y,G)$ is a function if and only if it is well-defined at each $x \in X$.

Answer (score 2):

[Yes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qnitg0nlz9). For all inputs, it is defined as simply the constant.

With regards to Maclaurin series, note that $\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}{(3)}=0 $ $\forall n\in\Bbb Z, n\ge1$, thus $f(x)=f(0)=3$

Answer (score 1):

The short (and imprecise) answer to your question is yes. But to answer this question precisely we should recall the definition of a [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition):

**Definition**: A **function** $f: X \to Y$ from a set $X$ to a set $Y$ is a set $G$ of ordered pairs $\{(x,y)~|~x \in X\}$ where there is exactly one pair $(x,y)$ for each $x$ in $X$. The set $X$ is called the **domain** of $f$; the set $Y$ is the **codomain**. The **range** of $f$ is the subset of $Y$ consisting of all $y$ such that $(x,y)$ is in $G$.

The key fact here is that the domain and codomain are part of the definition of a function: once a function (any function) is defined it is defined for all inputs.

In light of this key fact, the expression $y = 3$ does *not* define a function because the domain and codomain are not specified. For different choices of domain and codomain we obtain different functions. Here are some examples:

1. Let $X = Y = \mathbb{R}$ and $~f_1:X \to Y$ be given by $~f_1(x)=3$.
2. Let $X = \mathbb{R}$, $Y=\mathbb{Z}$ and $~f_2:X \to Y$ be given by $~f_2(x)=3$.
3. Let $X = \mathbb{R}$, $Y=\{3,4\}$ and $~f_3:X \to Y$ be given by $~f_3(x)=3$.
4. Let $X = \{3,4\}$, $Y=\{3,4\}$ and $~f_4:X \to Y$ be given by $~f_4(x)=3$.

So the precise answer to your question is that the expression $y=3$ is not a function. Once we specify a domain $X$ and codomain $Y$ (where $3 \in Y$) we can define a function by the set $\{(x,3)~|~x \in X\}$ and this is defined for all input values $x \in X$.

Comment: This is good, and in my opinion rather better than the other answers. A problem of the way functions are now introduced in the high-schools is that little attention is paid to the domain, and none whatever is paid to the codomain.